# Mean-square continuity of random process

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

Let $\xi_{t}$, $t\in$ $\mathbb{R}$ be the process with independent increments and continuous variance with respect to $t$. Is it true that $\xi_{t}$ is mean-square continuous?

For fixed $t\in{\mathbb{R}}$ $E({\xi_{t+h}-\xi_t})^2=D({\xi_{t+h}-\xi_t})+E^2({\xi_{t+h}-\xi_t})$. To obtain a counterexample, we must find a process with these properties and a discontinuous mean with respect to $t$. Is it possible or $\xi_t$ is mean-square continuous?

Answer (score 1):

Let $\xi_t=f(t)+X$  This process has independent increments and variance of $\xi_t$ is variance of $X$ for all $t$. But $E(\xi_{t+h}-\xi_t)^{2}=(f(t+s)-f(t))^{2}$. Take $f$ to be a discontinuous function.

Comment: If you want to make it less trivial you con consider $B(t)+f(t)$ where $B$ is standard Brownian motion.